# Using div to position elements in an html page

Tags: html

I am trying to use `<div>` to manage the relative position of elements of my page. I want the following :

```
Header 1
Some text A...                                    Data B
Some text C...

Header2
Some text D...                                    Data E
Some text F...
```

The html code I use (no CSS) is the following :

```
<html>
<head/>
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Header1</h1>
    <div>
      <div style="float: left; width: 70%">
        <p>
          Some text A
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        Data B
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left">
      Some text C...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Header2</h1>
    <div>
      <div style="float: left; width: 70%">
        <p>
          Some text D...
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        Data E 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left">
      <p>
        Some text F...
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I get is something that looks more like

```
Header1
Some text A...                                    Data B
                                                  Some text C...
                                                  Header2
Some text D...                                    Data E
                                                  Some text F...
```

As you can see, "Some text C...", "Header 2", and "Some text F..." are not positioned where I would like them. 
I suppose I am using `<div style="float: left">` incorrectly. How should I do this ?

Comment: have you tried flexbox ?

Comment: I will have to find another solution, due to an *old* version of Firefox deployed on client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox model

HTML :

```
<html>
<head/>
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Header1</h1>
    <div class='parent'>
      <div style="float: left; width: 70%">
        <p>
          Some text A
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        Data B
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left">
      Some text C...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Header2</h1>
    <div class='parent'>
      <div style="float: left; width: 70%">
        <p>
          Some text D...
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        Data E 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left">
      <p>
        Some text F...
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
.parent{
  display : flex;
  justify-content : space around;
  flex-direction : row
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I am new to html, I'll try and understand the flexbox principles. Many thanks.

Comment: Due to an ancient version of Firefox deployed on client side, I will have to find a solution without flexbox

Comment: okay ! thanks for the information i will suggest some other solution

Answer (score 1):

The immediate issue you're running into is that both `Some text A` and `Some text D` are wrapped in `<p>` tags. This is adding the default margin to them, therefore throwing off where you'd expect your floats to happen.

If you take a look at the HTML through the Chrome or Firefox Developer tools the highlighting will show you how that margin is affecting your float.

An easy fix to this is to use CSS to eliminate the margins on those items.

**Edit:** If you choose to go the Flexbox route then `justify-content: space-between;` may fit your needs better.